# How To Compare Objects By Name In Query Flutter by Property

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart, filter

I am adding a search bar in my application and trying to query a object by an attribute name but, cant get it working.

EDIT 1) Future function:

```
 Widget _buildDiner() {
        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FutureBuilder(
                      future: _setDiner,
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        var diner = snapshot.data;



                        if (snapshot.data == null) {
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        } else {
                          var sponsoredDiner = diner
                              .where((e) => e.sponsored == 'Yes')
                              .toList();


                          return Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              _makeDiner(sponsoredDiner),
                              _buildCoupon(),
                              _buildVendors()
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                      })
                ]));
      }
```

Diners =

```
class Diners {
  String keyword;
  int id;
  String name;
  String sponsored;

  Diners({
    this.keyword,
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.sponsored
  });

  factory Diners.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Diners(
        keyword: parsedJson['keyword'] as String,
        id: parsedJson['id'],
        name: parsedJson['name'] as String,
        sponsored: parsedJson['sponsored'] as String
    );
  }
}
```

And I am comparing two instances of Diners( sponsored and diners)

I use this query to attempt to compare the text that is put in to the search bar:

```
final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? sponsored
        : diners
            .where((p) => p.name.startsWith(query)).toList();
```

But I'm getting this error

"type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(Diner) => bool' of 'test'

I'm not sure why

Comment: Where you defined diners object?

Comment: In a future function. Updating code now to show

Comment: Dont you get the line number in the stack trace? There you can find where you made the mistake.

Comment: Yes it did. I didn't understand the error. That's why I came to here. For assistance.